# Filling Object[,] from List<User>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have a list of user objects:

```
List<User> users
```

Where as my user class is:

```
public class User
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }       
}
```

Can you please guide me how I can select `JoinDate` and `Name` as Object[,]

I need to pass this to a method which require Object[,]

Comment: @KenKin I need to pass this to a method which require Object[,]

Comment: [,] is 2-dim array. What do you want to have in each dim?

Comment: You can't get `object[,]` from LINQ using standard methods. Or any `[,]` array in general. That's impossible. You could get `object[][]`, but looks like that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek then let him write a converting Func<> :)

Answer (score 0):

you can write a linq to get the value

```
var v = (from f in users
         select new { f.JoinDate , f.Name });

foreach(object o in v.AsEnumerable()
{
   Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
}
```

Comment: if you want only object array then inside foreach loop you can create a object array like

Comment: You can do the same iterating on `users`, without creating another, anonymous type.